# create a certain dictionary from lists of unequal size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am zipping two lists into a dictionary and they are of unequal size:

```
list1 = [A,B,C]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I know its possible to zip them using cycle but that seems to work when the key is the longer list so `{'1': A, '2': B, '3': C, '4': A, '5': B, '6': C}`

I don't want that. I want the shorter list (list1) to be the key and the outcome to be

```
master_dict={A:[1,4],B:[2,5],C:[3,6]}
```

Comment: is list2 always the double size of list1 ?

Comment: Try to make working examples. `A` isn't a thing. Would changing it to `"A"` work for your example?

Comment: Show the non-working cycle code. We can't comment on what's wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Yes, it will always be double the size of list1.

Answer (score 2):

```py
master_dict = {
    k: list2[i::len(list1)]
    for i, k in enumerate(list1)
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VU9LCsIwEN3nFLNLC-OiP5FAF-oxQpCiKYa2aUlTUMSTuOlGD-ItvI1JWxcOzOb9Zt7j1V3tudXj-Bxsudp83rXqbQQ5cLqlSHdu91QQj8YejTDGBFPMcC2IvHTyaB18c2LmuFR4C-MxZsIbGU-c7k5IU_RWmsNJzXICbioGUyxXjNVSB9PlUExc2RpQCBUoDVIPjTSFlYuCuLzOKG2Dv9Qc5nfCuclS6FfsCw)

Answer (score 1):

```
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list1 = ['A','B','C']

k = [list2[x::3] for x in range(len(list1))]  # get the values from list2

print(k)
#[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

d = dict(zip(list1,k))

print(d)
#{'A': [1, 4], 'B': [2, 5], 'C': [3, 6]}
```

Comment: this worked but I changed 3 to len(list1)

Answer (score 1):

since you want to add element in rotation wise ie first fill n element of list1 key with list2 elemnt and then again for reamining list2 element fill it with in list1 elements in dictionary then , you can used `%` to get element index of list1 for which elemement index of list2 will go . below is code for it.

```
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list1 = ['A','B','C']

final_dict = {i: [] for i in list1}
for i, v in enumerate(list2):
    final_dict[list1[i%len(list1)]].append(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that `cycle` can't work, it's that you want lists of values from `list2`, not the values themselves. You could create a dictionary of lists for all values in list1 and then go back and append values from list2.

```
list1 = [A,B,C] # <--- this will error because not defined
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

result = {k:[] for k in list1}
for k, v in zip(cycle(list1), list2):
    result[k].append(v)
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're bothering pre-making the result rather than using a `defualtdict` or `setdefault()` in the loop?

Comment: @Mark - Its to handle the case where list1 is larger than list2. Its not really defined in the question either way, but this makes sure all values from list1 are in the dictionary.